# How to solve "Servlet error" when using database control in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

When I want to use Oracle 12c GUI, I receive an error as written below:

> Servlet error: An exception occurred.
>
> The current application deployment descriptors do   not allow for including it in this response. Please consult the application log for details.

My browser is Google Chrome, and the firewall and antivirus are also deactivated. I should also mention that I have started all Oracle services in services.msc section.
I have tried to use GUI by entering the address `https://pedcom-pc:1158/em` , too, but I received the same error.

That would be very helpful of you if you show me a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database control has been desupported in 12c. You need to use [EM Express or EM Could Control](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60005)

Comment: @mghaffari: What did you do to solve your problem? It's true that Database Control is no longer used, and it's now EM Express, but that just seems like a matter of terminology to me, since the URL you were using looks correct, if EM is configured for port 1158...